Is it possible to show that for $q>0$, $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{(\ln{x)^p}}{x^q} = 0$ without using L'Hopital's Rule?
Is it possible to show that for $q>0$, $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{(\ln{x)^p}}{x^q} = 0$ without using L'Hopital's Rule?
Applying L'Hopital's Rule repeatedly until the numerator becomes a constant does the trick, but I wondered if we could compute this limit by manipulation leading to well-known identities (e.g.$\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} \dfrac{\ln{x}}{x} = 0)$. This works if $p < q$ but is troublesome when $p > q$, which produces $0\cdot\infty$. I'm hoping to receive some guidance.
Thank you very much!

It’s (clearly) sufficient to consider the case where $q=1$. To solve this problem, you have to use some facts about the logarithm. Since the logarithm is defined as an integral, it seems hard to do this without appealing to Taylor series, or L’Hopital’s Rule, or similar.

Are you aware of the fact that $\ln x\le x^{\alpha}$ for large $x$ and any $\alpha>0$?

The Cauchy condensation test is pretty much designed for this series and its relatives (e.g. the generalized Bertrand series), but perhaps you want something not making use of "big-gun" methods such as L'Hopital or Cauchy condensation.

$$\limsup_{x \to \infty} \frac{\ln^p(x)}{x^q} = \limsup_{x \to \infty} \left( \frac{\ln(x)}{x^{\frac{q}{p}}} \right ) ^p = \left(\limsup_{x \to \infty}  \frac{\ln(x)}{x^{\frac{q}{p}}} \right ) ^p$$
Therefore, we may reduce to the case $p=1$.
$$\limsup_{x \to \infty} \frac{\ln(x)}{x^q} = \limsup_{x \to \infty} \frac{\ln(x^{\frac{1}{q}})}{x} = \limsup_{x \to \infty} \frac{\ln(x)}{qx} = \frac{1}{q} \limsup_{x \to \infty} \frac{\ln(x)}{x}$$
Thus, we may also reduce to $q =1$. Then, for any $a > 0$,
$$\limsup_{x \to \infty} \frac{\ln(x)}{x} = \limsup_{x \to \infty} \frac{\ln(ax)}{ax} = \limsup_{x \to \infty} \frac{\ln(a) + \ln(x)}{ax} = \limsup_{x \to \infty} \frac{\ln(x)}{ax}$$
$$\implies \limsup_{x \to \infty} \frac{\ln(x)}{x} = 0$$
On the other hand, both terms in the quotient are positive as $x \to \infty$, so clearly:
$$\liminf_{x \to \infty} \frac{\ln(x)}{x} \ge 0$$
We deduce that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\ln(x)}{x} = 0$ as required.
Edit: Thanks to Ryszard Szwarc for pointing out that we may only deduce that: $$\limsup_{x \to \infty} \frac{\ln(x)}{x} \in \{0, \infty\}$$ from the above.
In order to show that it is not $\infty$, we prove that $\frac{\ln(x)}{x} \le 1$ for all $x \ge 1$. We have that:
$$\lfloor x \rfloor \le x$$
$$\ln(\lceil x \rceil) \ge \ln (x)$$
Therefore, it suffices to prove that $\ln(n+1) \le n$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$
$$\iff n+1 \le e^n \text{ for every } n \in \mathbb{N}$$
and this follows easily by induction, or, even more easily from this observation due to Ryszard:
$$e^n > 2^n = (1+1)^n \ge 1+n$$
by the binomial theorem.

my TA briefly mentioned this scaling trick to evaluate $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln x}{x}$ several years ago, but I was too inexperienced to understand it (or even recall the argument years later) …till now :)

The trick works provided that we first make sure that the  function ${\ln x\over x}$ is bounded above.

@RyszardSzwarc Yes, good point. I will try to find an elementary way to prove this in the same manner as the above.

@peek-a-boo I previously saw part of this trick used by @ geetha290krm, and then with a little thought I realised that variations of it gave the full proof (almost, as Ryszard Szwarc points out).

$e^n>(1+1)^n\ge 1+n$ by the binomial formula.

@RyszardSzwarc Even better.

The proof can be made elementary, with no calculus methods whatsoever. It gives the upper bound by a constant times $(\ln x)^{-p}.$
We have $\ln 2<1.$ Thus $\ln (2^n)=n\ln 2<n.$ Hence for $n\ge 2$ we get $${\ln(2^n)\over 2^n}<{n\over 2^n}<{n\over {n\choose 2}}={2\over n-1}$$ For $t\ge e^2$ there is $n\ge 2$ such that $2^{n-1}\le t<2^{n}.$ Then $n>{\ln t\over \ln 2}>\ln t$ and $${\ln t\over t}\le  {\ln(2^n)\over 2^{n-1}}<{4\over n-1}<{8\over n}<{8\over \ln t}$$ Next for $p,q>0$ let $x=t^{p/q}$ for $t\ge e^2.$ Then $${(\ln x)^p\over x^q}={p^p\over q^p}\left ({\ln t\over t}\right )^p\\ \le {p^p\over q^p}\left ({8\over \ln t}\right )^p = {8^pp^{2p}\over q^{2p}}{1\over (\ln x)^p}$$ This implies that the limit in OP is equal $0.$

Assuming it is legal to use $e^s=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{s^k}{k!}.$
Let $x=e^t$ then $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(\ln x)^p}{x^q}=\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{t^p}{e^{qt}}\leq \lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{t^p}{(qt)^n/n!}$ for $n\geq1.$ Picking $n>p$ finishes the proof.

It's more an idea, rather than an answer. Notice that $$\frac{(\log x)^p}{x^q} = \exp\left[p \log \log x - q \log x\right] = \exp\left[\log x\left(p\frac{\log \log x}{\log x} - q\right)\right],$$ and we have that $\frac{\log \log x}{\log x} \le \frac{q}{p}$ for large enough $x$.
